# Need help with Cross Compiling libraries for ros android ndk

Tags: ros, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described here [ros_android_ndk](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/How%20to%20cross-compile%20any%20ROS%20package),  I am trying to cross compile some libraries for ros android ndk.
My first problem is that when i add new packages with rosfusion.py in the ndk.rosinstall and they fail to compile  I cant get them out anymore. Even if I delete the new dependencies or comment them out the ./do_docker.sh fails because of the new dependencies. Do I miss a step here?(Solved see answers)
I need 2 Packages that arent included yet:
depthimage_to_laserscan and map_server.
Sadly map_server is commented out. Is  there any workaround?
depthimage_to_laserscan the kinetic fails as well. But the indigo release seems to crosscompile correctly because it doesn't depend on opencv3.
Now that it has compiled how do I use it?
Do I just include the header file? Do i need to copy the code or do I have to declare it in the Android.mk file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301927/need-help-with-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ros-android-ndk/) by [manster2209](https://answers.ros.org/users/35175/manster2209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding your second question: if map_server is commented out it's most probably because I has some issues to compile. If you really need it you might try to fix those and submit a PR, it will be most welcome.
On your third question: if you have added a new package and it has compiled you can now use it as any other ros package and you will need to add the binary to the Android.mk list so it gets statically linked.
Hope this was useful.

---

Originally posted by [Ernesto Corbellini](https://answers.ros.org/users/23887/ernesto-corbellini/) with karma: 101 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0